# How to add game like animation in app

Tags: android, andengine

I am working on educational app.It allows to take test, review answers, generate mark sheet etc.

Now i wanna add one more module. Just like chemistry practicals. That is user will add input for two solutions after that i need to show two test tube having that solutions then will mix it up and give the produced solution.
This all activity i need to show in animated format. But am not sure what to use for creating such animations.I want it in the form of small game inside app.

i can not use animated videos because i need to get input from user first like solution names, number of solutions to be used and quantity of solution.And need to show output as resultant output from reacted solutions.

I have google a lot. And still not sure about what to use. Don't know is this done by adding animation effect on images or anything else. Can any one please suggest me?

Comment: reason for down vote? I found stackoverflow best for any program related queries. Give the reason for down vote also. so that i can improve further.

Comment: If the animation you are trying to achieve is common, i mean this animation will be shown everywhere without any changes what so ever, then you could create an animation video(or find a suitable one from youtube/any video platforms) and then add it in a VideoView instead of creating this animation using code or frames. It will be so much easier.

Comment: but i need to get input from user like how many solutions, which solutions and quantity of solution. accordingly we need to generate output. how i can i achieve this using fixed video?

Comment: the downvotes I'm assuming it's because you have a very broad question with zero code and no way of giving a precise answer. "game like" I can only point you on how games do. You either have a custom view that directly draw on the `Canvas` object during the `onDraw(canvas)` callback, or SurfaceView for drawing the same stuff without hogging the main thread, or use a 2D game engine (like libGdx or several others u can find using google)

Comment: thanks for explanation. Am new in game environment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a spritesheet. If you don't know how, learn it.

```
public class Player {

    public int x, y;
    private int width, height;
    Animation animation;
    public Player(int x, int y,int width, int height, Bitmap res, int numFrames) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
        spritesheet = res;

        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
            image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
        }

        animation.setFrames(image);
        animation.setDelay(10);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public void tick() {
        animation.update();
    }

    public void render(Canvas g) {
        g.drawBitmap(animation.getImage(), (float)x, (float)y, null);
    }
}
```

The Animation class is a custom one:

```
public class Animation {
    private Bitmap[] frames;
    private int currentFrame;
    private long startTime;
    private long delay;
    private boolean playedOnce;

    public void setFrames(Bitmap[] frames){
       this.frames = frames;
        currentFrame = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    public void setDelay(long d){delay = d;}
    public void setFrame(int i){currentFrame= i;}

    public void update(){
        long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;

        if(elapsed>delay){
            currentFrame++;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        if(currentFrame == frames.length){
            currentFrame = 0;
            playedOnce = true;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getImage(){
        return frames[currentFrame];
    }
    public int getFrame(){return currentFrame;}
    public boolean playedOnce(){return playedOnce;}
}
```

This is how I do animation. Make a long strip and insert smaller images of the same width and height in it. I don't think this supports spritesheets that go in the height though. But it animates

**EDIT:**

This animates which is what the title of the question says you were asking how to do. As of mixing spritesheets and all of that is up to you. This takes in a spritesheet and the number of frames and the location to render it and it animates. If there is something else you need to know, edit the question

Comment: thanks for the reply. but  as i said i need to get input from user first. so accordingly do i need to create multiple spritesheets for different chemical solutions?